# How to Add Button with Permission on Datatables Laravel

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I am a beginner for datatables. I have successfully added a button on each line. But, I got one problem. How do I add permissions like

```
@can ('theresia-create')
//button
@endcan
```

If on a blade, I can use @can & @endcan but here it can't. So, what should I do?

**Controller**:

```
    return Datatables::of($kamar)
    ->addColumn('action', function ($data) {
        return '
        <form action="'. route('kamar_theresia.destroy', $data->id) .'" method="POST">
        <a href="kamar_theresia/'.$data->id.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-info"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Show</a>
        <a href="kamar_theresia/'.$data->id.'/edit" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</a>
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="'. csrf_token() .'">
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-delete" data-remote="kamar_theresia/'.$data->id.'" data-toggle="confirmation"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a></button>
        </form>
        ';
    })
    ->editColumn('id', 'ID: {{$id}}')
    ->make(true);
```

**View**

```
<table id="kamar" class="text-center table table-bordered">
  <thead class="text-capitalize">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Kelas</th>
      <th>Ketersediaan</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var editor;
    $('#kamar').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: 'http://localhost:8000/dataTheresia',
        columns: [
            {data: 'nama', name: 'kamar_theresia.nama'},
            {data: 'name', name: 'kelas_theresia.name'},
            {data: 'ketersediaan', name: 'kamar_theresia.ketersediaan'},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
            ]
        });
</script>
```

Comment: permissions like '@can ('theresia-create') //button @endcan'

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="'. route('kamar_theresia.destroy', $data->id) .'" method="POST">
 {{ csrf_field() }}
        <a href="kamar_theresia/'.$data->id.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-info"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Show</a>
        <a href="kamar_theresia/'.$data->id.'/edit" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</a>
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="'. csrf_token() .'">
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-delete" data-remote="kamar_theresia/'.$data->id.'" data-toggle="confirmation"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a></button>
        </form>
```

Comment: {{ csrf_field() }} , I have added it and it appears on the page.